# editpad regex. Searching files for "http://" but excluding "http://particular.domain.com"

Tags: regex, editpad

I'm using RegexBuddy and getting nowhere defining a search parameter for editpad.

I'm trying to search through my CMS web site for all instances of "http://" (to see where the protocol was hardcoded incorrectly), but every file has "http://particular.domain.com" in the comments near the top of the file.

How can I search for all EXCEPT those?  This seems like it should be basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your expression:

```
http:\/\/(?!particular\.domain\.com).+
```

Check out a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/eT2cX8/2

This portion is called a negative lookahead that lets you negate that match:

```
(?!particular\.domain\.com).+
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did read about negative lookaheads and somehow wasn't able to get it all together.  It makes sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: I've always thought that term makes it sound really confusing.

Comment: So then I started thinking.. maybe I could use a negative look behind to cut out anything that's in a comment.  So I tried this:  http:\/\/(?<!\/\/).+ but got no love.  What am I missing there?

Answer (score 1):

use a negative lookahead:

```
'(?!http://particular.domain.com)http://'
```

is an example of a pattern that would match any http:// text EXCEPT the particular one